# Audio effects with NaCl extension

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I have just started investigating NaCl in the hopes of making an audio browser extension. There is a sine wave demo in the documentation, so it seems that making a synthesizer would be trivial.

I am interested to know if it is possible to capture the browser audio stream before it is output so that real-time effects can be applied. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is it possible. I've done it. You create a ScriptProcessorNode whose onaudioprocess callback takes the inputbuffer and passes it to a waiting NaCl module via postMessage. Once the NaCl module is finished processing it sends it back to JavaScript via postMessage. The ScriptProcessorNode must output something so you introduce a 1 frame delay and the ScriptProcessorNode copies the most recent processed output received from NaCl.

The Flow looks like this:

ScriptProcessorNode -> postMessage input buffer to NaCl

ScriptProcessorNode -> copy most recent buffer received from NaCl into output buffer.

NaCl -> Receives audio sample buffer, processes it and posts it back.

Let me know if you want me to post the code on GitHub or have anymore questions.

HTH,
John

Comment: Yes please! That would be awesome.